# Can't get Android ApiDemos to work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android

I feel a bit stupid since I develop android apps for a while now. My problem is that I can't get the ApiDemos to work with Eclipse.
Please have a look at the screenshot of my errors I get in Eclipse:
http://cheat-database.com/android.png

It looks like it can't find the xml files in the ApiDemos project. Although everything looks fine to me.
Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?

Other (own) Android applications work fine in Eclipse.
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Did you try to clean the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R.java is an automatically generated file. It is updated/re-generated whenever layout files, etc are changed.

I'm going to assume you tried to set up the project directly from the samples. I've seen that cause issues with write access if you don't have the privileges, and it doesn't seem to play nice when I try it either.

One thing to try would be copying the relevant ApiDemos folder to an alternate location and then try creating a new android project from that folder as follows:

Create -> New Android Project -> Create Project From Existing Source

Then point it to the location and select the relevant SDK.

It's not ideal, but at least it might get the application generating and running possibly.

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried it how you described. Unfortunately I get the error from Eclipse "Invalid project description.... ApiDemos overlaps the location of another project: ApiDemos"
Although I don't have another project with that name in my workspace. Might there be some data left in Eclipse which I have to clean first?

Comment: If you delete a project from your eclipse workspace, the files may still be left there, just not visible. Navigate to the workspace folder and check if there is already an "ApiDemos" there. If so, delete it and try again.

Answer (score 5):

Do this: In Eclipse, File->New->Project, then either type the word "sample" in the filter text field or select Android->Android Sample Project and you will see all the projects such as ApiDemos, NotePad, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project and build it again...I hope it would solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

when you File->New->Other->Android Project from Existing Code, you have to tick "Copy projects into workspace".

Answer (score 0):

got the same issue today :-(

this way gave me a solution very easy to use with ADT (eclipse) :

click on New Project icon --> Project --> Android --> Android Sample Project --> Next --> Select Target (for me Android 4.4) --> Next --> and then select the sample project you want to import in Eclipse (for me : legacy > ApiDemo) --> Finish

it works fine for me, i hope that could help someone :-)

@+Mathieu