# Can't get my Android project work (Mac, Eclipse, eGit)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, egit

I'm working with GitHub from two laptops: windows and mac.
I develop Android applications using Eclipse as IDE and GitHub for version control.
I created a repository on GitHub. I created an Android project. Then, I made 6 commits from my Windows laptop to the repository on GitHub.
Then I installed Eclipse on my Macbook.
I imported the project from GitHub. But when I try to run it, it shows me an error `R cannot be resolved to a variable`.
I found that this is a widespread error. But I haven't found a solution for my problem. The following solution didn't work in my case:
[Can't get Android ApiDemos to work in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545138/cant-get-android-apidemos-to-work-in-eclipse)

Comment: First thing I would try is right click on the project and choose Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason `"Android SDK Build Tools"` were not installed. So, to solve this problem I went to AVD Manager, selected (checked) `"Android SDK Build Tools"` and clicked `"Install"`